# Python How to list all methods/classes that have been imported into a class

Tags: python, function

How to list all methods/classes that have been imported into a class. Take an example

```
from module1 import method1
from module2 import method2

class foo(object):
   def say_foo(self):
      method1()
   def talk(self):
      method2()
```

is it possible to list all methods used in  the `foo` class? i know `inspect.getmembers(foo)` will list `talk` and `say_foo`, how do i list `method1` and `method2`?

Comment: The code of `say_foo()` will only contain a reference to the global name `method1`, and during the execution of `say_foo()` the name will be resolved to whatever object this global name points to at the time of execution.  This might be a totally different object than what `method1` points to at the time of definition of `say_foo()`.  (Moreover, the nomenclature in `from module1 import method1` does not make much sense.  There are no "methods" at module level in Python.)

Comment: @Sven, i shld have said function rather than method?!

Comment: Yes, that's how they are called in Python, but this comment was only a side note.  My main point is that what you are trying to do does not make much sense.

Comment: @Sven It’s still a reasonable question. The correct answer is to explain how variable bindings really work in Python.

Comment: @jleedev: Isn't this what I did in my comment?  (Not my downvote, btw.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ast module to analyze you code:

```
code = """
from module1 import method1
from module2 import method2

class foo(object):
   def say_foo(self):
      method1()
   def talk(self):
      method2()
"""

import ast, _ast

t = ast.parse(code)
for node in ast.walk(t):
    if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef) and node.name == "foo":
        klass = node
        break

for node in ast.walk(klass):
    if isinstance(node, _ast.Call):
        print node.func.id
```

the output is :

```
method1
method2
```

Answer (score 3):

To be brutally honest, your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense, and here is why:

At the point when `foo` is defined, no connection is made between the two globals called by `say_foo` and `talk` and the two functions imported at the top of your code.

For example, the interpreter will not complain about the following:

```
class foo(object):
   def say_foo(self):
      method1()
   def talk(self):
      method2()
```

Despite the absence of imports, this is still valid code. You won't of course be able to call `say_foo` and `talk` without getting a `NameError`.

The following is also fine:

```
from module1 import method1
from module2 import method2

class foo(object):
   def say_foo(self):
      method1()
   def talk(self):
      method2()

obj1 = foo()
obj1.say_foo()

def method1(): pass

obj1.say_foo()
obj2 = foo()
obj2.say_foo()
```

I leave to you to figure out which `method1` gets invoked when.

Now, having said all that, there is something you *can* do. If you examine the method object's `co_names`, that'll give you the [list of names that are used by the method](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/WhatCoNamesIs):

```
In [30]: foo.say_foo.im_func.func_code.co_names
Out[30]: ('method1',)

In [31]: foo.talk.im_func.func_code.co_names
Out[31]: ('method2',)
```

**This clearly isn't exactly the same as what you're asking**, and may or may not be useful depending on what you intend to do with this.

It is also almost certainly CPython-specific.

Answer (score 1):

What? `method1` and `method2` haven't been "imported into" the `foo` class. They're imported in the module, so `dir(foomodule)` will show them. But there's simply no reference from `foo` to `method1`.